# Angular 2/Mongoose: Called server function not invoked

Tags: angular, mongoose

I have two nearly identical functions in my service: getProducts() and getProductsByType() which make calls to the server.  The getProductsByType() calls the server function and returns data. The getProducts() function calls its corresponding server function but the server function is never invoked.

Service functions:

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  private products: Product[];  

  private productsUrl: string = "/api/products/all";
  private productUrl: string = "/api/products/";

  constructor(private http: Http) { 
    this.getProducts();
  }

  public getProducts() {
    console.log("DataService.getProducts called");

    this.http.get(this.productsUrl)
    .map((response: Response) => {
      this.products = response.json();
    })
    .catch(this.handleError)    
  }

  public getProductsByType(type: string): Observable<Product[]> {
    console.log("DataService.getProductsByType called");

    return this.http.get(this.productUrl + type)
    .map((response: Response) => {
      return response.json() as Product[] || null;
    })
    .catch(this.handleError)    
  }
}
```

Server functions:

```
router.get("/products/:type", function (req, res) {
console.log("Get product by type called")

Product.find({ "producttype": req.params.type })
    .exec(function (err, products) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error retrieving products: " + req.params.type);
            res.json(err);
        } else {
            // console.log("products = " + JSON.stringify(products));
            res.json(products);
        }
    });
})

router.get("/products/all", function (req, res) {
    console.log("Get product called")

    Product.find({})
        .exec(function (err, products) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error retrieving products");
                res.json(err);
            } else {
                console.log("products = " + JSON.stringify(products));
                res.json(products);
            }
        });
})
```

Comment: Hummm, so you don't see console.log("Get product called") getting logged? or you don't see console.log("products = " + JSON.stringify(products)); getting logged?

Comment: Neither is logged.

Comment: Sorry it has been a minute since I used express. Maybe express is matching "/api/products/all" against your first route and interpreting "all" as an argument. Maybe try reordering the routes or calling next() in your "/products/:type" route. I gotta get goin, sorry I couldn't be of more help. Good luck!

Comment: Remove /all in both places to test

Comment: I did already. Same result.

Comment: Have you 'switched' the routers ?

Answer (score 0):

First I changed the url of the http from "/products/all to /allproducts because it seems the latter conflicted with an existing url "/products/:type. This did not immediately solve the problem. I then changed the function from using Observable to using Promise as shown below and the data was received. There may be some quirk with Observables. It worked in one instance and not the other.

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  private products: Product[];  

  private productsUrl: string = "/api/allproducts";

  constructor(private http: Http) { 
    this.getProducts();
  } 

 public getProducts() {
    console.log("DataService.getProducts called");

    this.http.get(this.productsUrl)
      .toPromise()
      .then((response: Response) => {
        this.products = response.json()
        console.log("DataService.products = " + JSON.stringify(this.products));
      })
      .catch(this.handleError)    
  }

}
```